# How to translate "the movie deserves better than what it got at the box office", specifically the "got" part in Japanese

Tags: grammar, phrases

I'm trying to explain this english phrase in Japanese, specifically the "got" part of this phrase. I'm a native English speaker, but I'm not a teacher so it's difficult to explain this phrase for my Japanese friends. Does anyone have a Japanese explanation on how to the word "got" is used in this sentence?

Comment: Are you hoping to preserve the colloquial nature of it?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be necessary. More so if there's a logically explanation of the usage of "for" in the context of this phrase. Preferably explained in the lens of the Japanese grammar, if possible!

Comment: As it is, this is more or less a translation request, which is off-topic. You may want to add what you see in the dictionary and why you think it does not convey the English meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this falls under a translation request, but your post is not very informative either. For example, could you tell us why do you find it difficult to explain (like you were asked about it)?

Comment: What "for" are you talking about?